# How to read an Element from QForm PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm making a QForm and add the Items in this way:

```
def draw_new_container(self, iteams):
    for i in range(len(iteams)):
        label =QtWidgets.QLabel(self.QFormLayoutWidget)
        self.read_style("label.css",label)
        label.setText(iteams[i])
        enter = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.QFormLayoutWidget)
        self.read_style("LineEdit.css",enter)
        self.QFormLayout.addRow(label, enter)
```

and when I want to read the text in all of the QLineEidet I do it in this way:

```
for i in range(len(self.check_items())):
        widget_item = self.QFormLayout.itemAt(i, 1)
        widget = widget_item.widget()
        text = widget.text()
        print(text)
```

I always become this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'widget'

why I'm getting this error? and how can I read them in the right way?

Comment: What is the value `self.check_items()`? And is it always less than or equal to `self.QFormLayout.rowCount()`?

Comment: They are always equal

Comment: Do you add any rows or items to the layout at any other point in your code? Anyway, instead of accessing the line edits via the QLayoutItems you are probably better off storing the line edits in a dict or a list when adding them to the layout and accessing them via this dict/list.

Comment: I will try it thanks